# I'm getting empty space between uipickerview and toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uitoolbar

When I'm setting height of the UIPickerview is 120 and adding toolbar button as InputAcessoryView then it showing me empty space between them.. But when I'm not setting height it working fine.

I want to set fix height as 120 and also don't want empty space between them.

Comment: Please add a portion of your code.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?